# 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called' in unittest

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to create a test Class in Python using a fixture and verify if my function is called inside the test

The test class:

```
    from unittest.mock import ANY
    from path_to_class.extract_class_test import TestExtract
    import unittest 
    from mock import patch, call
    from unittest.mock import ANY
    import pytest
    
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def test_hook_class_mock():
        with patch('path_to_hook_class.classHookName.get_test_data') as mock:
            yield mock
    
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("test_hook_class_mock")        
    class TestExtract(unittest.TestCase):
    
        def test_if_the_request_method_is_called(self):
            example_test_endpoint = 'test'
            
            test_extract_class = TestExtract
            test_extract_class.execute(endpoint=example_test_endpoint)
            
            test_hook_class_mock.assert_called()
```

The class tested:

```
import logging
from path_to_hook_class import classHookName

class TestExtract():
          
    def execute(endpoint):
        test_hook= classHookName(endpoint=endpoint, header='test')
        response = test_hook.get_test_data()
        
        return response
```

The error I'm getting is

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called'
```

***Testing out of the class,the test passed***

Comment: you forgot to add your fixture to your test function parameters, it's referencing the global function instead of a mock passed in

Comment: when I add the fixture to my test function parameters, I'm getting the error `TypeError: test_if_the_request_method_is_called() missing 1 required positional argument: 'test_hook_class_mock'`

Comment: I think that you should use mock of pytest instead of unittest.mock

Comment: pytest's `unittest` mode is only meant as a migration mechanism -- since you're not using any functionality of unittest you should remove the `unittest.TestCase` base class, then you'll be able to use pytest fixtures - a pytest core dev